# How to render form wizard with message and with data preserved?

Tags: python, django, recaptcha

I have a form wizard that checks if google recaptcha is valid. If not, the form shows a message that it is invalid and please try again. The issue is that the form forgets its data when this happens, so if the user tries to submit the form again, instead of submitting normally, the form goes back to step 1 because it doesn't have all the data. Any ideas on how to remedy this? Here is the code:

```
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    recaptcha_response = self.request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
    url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'
    values = {
            'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
            'response': recaptcha_response
    }
    captcha = urllib.parse.urlencode(values).encode()
    req =  urllib.request.Request(url, data=captcha)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    result = json.loads(response.read().decode())

    if result['success']:
        *** success logic ***
    else:
        form = self.get_form(step=self.steps.current, data=self.request.POST, files=self.request.FILES)
        messages.add_message(self.request, messages.ERROR, 'Invalid captcha. Please try again.')
        return super(FormView, self).render(form, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using old Django 1.7 or older to use Form Wizard, but I have used [Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/) as part of multi-step forms. And I have used [Django Session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/) to store data. For example:

```
class StepOneView(FormView):
    form_class = StepOneForm
    template_name = 'step_one.html'
    success_url = '/step-two/'

    def get_initials(self):
        initial = super(StepOneView, self).get_initial()
        return self.request.session.get('step_one', {})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.request.session['step_one'] = form.cleaned_data
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Here, on `form_valid` I have stored cleared_data in session with a **key**(here its *step_one*). And when loading the initial data, I just get those from session with the **key**.

And after successful submission, delete the session data like this:

```
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    ...
    if result['success']:
        del self.request.session['step_one']

        self.request.session.modified = True
        # rest of the logics
    ...
```

Comment: I'm using 1.11. Thanks for answering ruddra. I am going to try to implement this and I'll get back to you on if it was successful or not.